# Find the least value $f=\frac{(a+1)^3}{2b}+\frac{(b+1)^3}{a}$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b>0$ find the minimum of the value
$$f=\dfrac{(a+1)^3}{2b}+\dfrac{(b+1)^3}{a}$$
it seem can use AM-GM inequality,But not equal it

Comment: Are you given any other relation between $a$ and $b$?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gradient+(x%2B1)%5E3%2F(2y)%2B(y%2B1)%5E3%2Fx

Comment: Wolfram alpha does not find a closed-form solution: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+(a%2B1)%5E3+%2F(2+b)+%2B+(b%2B1)%5E3%2Fa, which makes me wonder if there is one.

Comment: Where do you get this problem? I doubt this problem can be solved through pure algebra or calculus. $f$ is minimized at $(x_0,y_0) \approx (0.5820985294926279,0.432647019026929)$ with value $\approx 9.628044484718595$. The problem is $x_0, y_0$ are roots of two quintic polynomials!
$$\begin{align}4096x^5+2048x^4-1664x^3+352x^2-517x+1 = 0\\
8192y^5+4096y^4-3328y^3+704y^2-305y+2 = 0\end{align}$$